# Repeatedly send http requests very fast

Tags: java, android, http

I need to send a http request to a url every 500 miliseconds (0,5 seconds). I dont necessarily need the response.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
Handler h = new Handler;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

h.postDelayed(new Runnable {
    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        Log.i("DriveCommand", response.getStatusLine().toString());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            instream.close();
        }
        h.postDelayed(this, 500);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, 500);
```

The problem with this code is that it's not sending the command consequently. Maybe it's waiting for the response, before it sends the next one?

Comment: Undeleting at OP's request to provide an opportunity to edit/improve. Please do not delete for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an async HTTP library like Volley or OkHttp. Volley adds the requests to a queue and doesn't wait for a response. (It just sends the new request, just like I wanted).

I'm still using the Handler (but now in combination with Volley, instead of using the built-in http tools of Android) and it's working like a charm!